# Regarding quadratic probing in hashing

Tags: algorithm, hash

I am reading on quadratic probing at following link: http://www.brpreiss.com/books/opus5/html/page241.html

Here what does author mean first `M/2` probes are distinct. In what context is the author talking about distinct?

In addtion why (mod M) is only one side in proof, my understanding is that it should be on both sides as
              (h(x) + c(i)) mod M = (h(x) + c(j)) mod M

question is why author is mentioned only one side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the first floor `M/2` probes following the quadratic probing rule probe floor `M/2` distinct locations (`M` is prime).